# How can I check if any links are clicked on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a page with several modes drawn based on a php variable (view, edit, add). I have some jquery adding info to `td` tags, but it would always post to the `ajax` target php file (and block some links/behavior). So to fix it, I had to add a check to only show on view mode.

However, now the edit mode for some reason also shows view for the same variable I am checking and I can't change the class that does it. What I'd like to do is execute my code by default, except when any link is pressed (so it will always follow the link). How can I do that?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){


var msg ='<?php echo $mode; ?>';
if(msg == 'view'){
//get all appointment numbers
     count=0;

appointment_nums = [];
$('.mgrid_table > tbody > tr').each(function() {


    appointment_nums.push($(this).find('td').eq(3).find('label').html());

});
appointment_nums = appointment_nums.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 

appointments = appointment_nums.length;

function ajax() {
    return $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "../testrequest.php",
        data : {appointment_nums:appointment_nums},
        dataType:'json',
    });
    };

     ajax().done(function(result){

    $('table:nth-of-type(2) > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(2)').each(function() {    
     if($(this).children().length < 1){
    if (result[count] == false){
    $(this).append('<a href="index.php?patient=test&a='+appointment_nums[count]+'">Schedule Appointment </a>');
      }else{
        $(this).append('<span>Waiting For Doctor to Schedule</span>');
        }
   }
    count = count + 1 ;
    });

  });
   }
  });
      </script>
```

Comment: **However, now the edit mode for some reason also shows view for the same variable I am checking and I can't change the class that does it.** I'm having a hard time understanding this sentence. The code you posted also seems somewhat broad for a minimum reproducible example; is the issue specific to PHP, or JavaScript? If it's the former, only post HTML/PHP. If it's the latter, only post JavaScript (with hardcoded PHP results)

Comment: There is a variable called mode that I check, mode is used in a php function draw_page($mode)  that does all the html and stuff and since I can't change that class, I have to manipulate a a column with jquery. The problem is, that variable is actually the same. Instead there is a function attached to the link. So the mode is still view but another function should be called on link press to make it display edit mode. Basically, I need to put in the first if statement if msg = view and if no links clicked, then manipulate the data. otherwise, the page is showing other info and don't want to.

Comment: And what I need to know is how I can check if nothing was clicked in that if statement, I know how to check by id and stuff, but this particular link actually has no id or class. Also, I can't really make it reproducible because it requires quite a lot of info, this is just the one part in question. But it's a pretty simple issue.